# Is transpose of basis vectors still a basis for the original vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis, transpose

Consider the basis of a vector space, for the sake of a concrete example I am going to consider the canonical basis for $\mathbb R ^2$:

$\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\rbrace$

Is the set of row vectors formed by the transpose of each of these basis vectors still considered a basis for $\mathbb R ^ 2$? E.g. is the following still a basis for $\mathbb R ^2$?:

$\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}\rbrace$

My understanding of this may hinge on not understanding if 'row' vectors are in the same space as column vectors. For example, if the vectors I gave in the second basis example are even in $\mathbb R ^2$.

Comment: As you say, row vectors and column vectors are not elements of the same vector space. One can certainly identify $\mathbb R^2$ with either $2 \times 1$ matrices or $1 \times 2$ matrices, and there's an obvious isomorphism between them, but it would not be correct to say that they are bases for the *same* space.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_of_a_linear_map The transposed basis is a basis of the dual of $\Bbb R^2$. That said, in finite dimension, a vector space $E$ and its dual $E^*$ are always isomorphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about the same set of vectors presented differently. Of course if one set is a basis, the other set is also a basis. The problem makes more  sense if we talk about a matrix where the rows could be linearly independent  but the columns not or the other way around.

Comment: So is it safe to say both basis are in R2?

Comment: yes,it,is,safe to say both are basis for $R^2$